# ip route - connecting two tun dev

Tags: 12.04, server, openvpn, nat, gateway

Im trying to get two tun dev connected. 
If got everything, but the nat running.
One tun is secure connection and the other tun for internet access.

If got everything, but the nat running. There is a table "vpn".

I have

```
ip rule add dev tun1 table vpn
ip rule add from ip_tun1/24 table vpn
```

but the `ip route add default via ip_tun0/24 table vpn` won't work.

The command `ip route add nat 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.4.30.0/24 table vpn` doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "doesn´t work." why not? (or... what is the message you get?)

Comment: @Rinzwind "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument"

Comment: The /24  is probably wrong. Change the netmask to 255.255.255.255 and try again.

Comment: Thx @Rinzwind. But there was a way without changing the netmask. I already used it once. But its gone... I have "ip rule add dev tun1 table vpn" -> "ip rule add from ip_von_tun1/24 table vpn"...but the "ip route add default via ip_tun0/24 table vpn" won´t work. So i try to find the missing `link`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the routing done correctly, then the NAT can be added by `iptables` commands. For instance letting the network `10.0.3.0/24` out via NAT requires:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.3.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Beware, `ip route add nat ...` is not supported anymore...